# Does playing sound effects have to be filtering enabled?

Tags: roblox

In roblox I made a sword that plays the unsheath sound when equipped. This works by using a local script tell a server script to play it when equipped. I made a whole new remote event in replicated storage just for playing this sound effect and nothing else.

Is it really true that simply playing sound effects required filtering enabled?

Is all that extra work of creating the equipted event in replicated storage actually necessary or can I just play it in a non local script in the sword?

Comment: What did you mean by filtering? I'm not familiar with the Roblox API, but when I skimmed the [sound effect documentation](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/SoundEffect) I didn't see any mention of that term.Are you referring to the Roblox anti-exploit mechanism?

Comment: @Pikalek Yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should be. If they aren't, only the client that plays them will be able to hear them. So yes, if you want other players to be able to hear the sword coming out of the sheath, then they have to be filtering enabled.